# create ad that related to instagram post with facebook marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api

**TL;DR: how to create ad in business manager that connected to instagram post?**

I am using facebook marketing api to creating ads in the business manager that promote posts from my facebook page. I have instagram business account that connected with my facebook page and I want to be able creating ad with posts from my instagram account through the facebook marketing api (or any other api), this is possible?

my code for creating ads with posts from my facebook page:

**Creating ad creative**

```
adsSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(accessToken);

const AdAccount = adsSdk.AdAccount;
const account = new AdAccount(accountId);

let fields = ['id', 'object_story_id'];
let params = {
    'name': 'Ad Creative test',
    'effective_instagram_story_id': facebookPostId
};

account.createAdCreative(fields, params).then(res =>{
    console.log(`ad creative created successfully with id ` + res.id);
});
```

**Creating ad**

```
adsSdk.FacebookAdsApi.init(accessToken);

const AdAccount = adsSdk.AdAccount;
const account = new AdAccount(accountId);

let fields = ['id'];
let params = {
    'name': 'New Ad',
    'adset_id': adsetId,
    'creative': '{\'creative_id\':' + creativeId + '}',
    'status': 'PAUSED',
};

account.createAd(fields, params).then(res => {
    console.log(`ad created successfully with id ` + id);
});
```

If I just giving instagram post id instead of facebook post id I get error.

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: you will need to say more about what you already know. repeating the same sentences in different sequence could mean that is all you understand. from your profile it seems you understand many java principals, but always have trouble linking things together?

Answer (score 0):

Create add using

```
new AdAccount(id, context).createAdCreative()
      .setName("Promoted Post")
      .setObjectStoryId("<pageID>_<postID>")
      .execute();
```

You can verify that your instagram account is linked using `instagram_accounts` if not try `page_backed_instagram_accounts`

for verify try to implement:

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/[pageId]?fields=instagram_accounts
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/[pageId]?fields=page_backed_instagram_accounts

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer,can you verify the way i used to create instagram ad creative is correct 
1)call facebookpageid?fields=instagram_accounts

2)take instagram_accounts[data][0][id]

3)setObjectStoryId as instagram_accounts[data][0][id]_instagrampostid